# Why are translations not counterexamples of Brouwer fixed point theorem?

Tags: general-topology

Sorry if this is an obvious one, but why is the following not a counterexample to the theorem?

A rescalling of the unit disc (centered at $(0, 0)$ in $R^2$) to a disc of radius 1/2 also centered at the origin, followed by the translation $(x+1/3, y)$.

I'm clearly missing the main idea of the theorem.

Comment: Because it has a fixed point?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Shouldn't the translation "unfix" any point?

Comment: Look at $(2/3,0)$. It goes to $(1/3,0)$ by the contraction, and to $(1/3+1/3,0)=(2/3,0)$.

Comment: It is the composition that is the map that is properly one of the unit disk to itself and that has a fixed point. The "translation helper map" is not a self-map of the disk.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks, this was my misconception...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a solution to the system below?

$$\left\{\begin{align}
x &= \frac12x + \frac13\\
y &= \frac12y
\end{align}
\right.$$

Comment: Makes sense.  It seems I let my intuition take over and forgot about basic algebra...

Comment: While this particular example can be tackled by simple algebra, Brouwer's fixed point theorem is powerful and holds true even when we don't have simple descriptions like this, which can be dealt with explicitly.